# Transistor part number and equivalent part

Tags: transistors, identification

Can someone help me identify the transistor part number in the image? I thought it might be KAY1704, but I get no matches. I get a match on KTA1704, which also lists A1704-Y as a part number. It appears that KSA1220 is a good match to KTA1704. Neither is available at Mouser or Digikey.

Any suggestions on available equivalent transistors? The transistor is used in a freezer fan control circuit.

[image]

Comment: How do you know it's bad?   I see a suspect looking resistor in that picture.

Comment: Here you go:     https://www.aliexpress.us/item/3256803082176261.html?gatewayAdapt=glo2usa4itemAdapt&_randl_shipto=US

Comment: A green part with black on it.  I'd look there as opposed to  the first transistor we see.

Comment: It is the transistor behind the first one in the picture and was physically damaged, leaving burnt marks on the board and the resistor. The resistor is test good. The green inductor in the background was connected to the bad transistor. I plan to replace the transistor and inductor.

Comment: Kyle B. Thanks for the link. Interesting. The part is labeled "KTA1704-Y" on the page but has same KAY1704 on the transistor pictured.  Must be same part. I don't understand why one is KAY and other is KTA.

Comment: The part will not arrive until 13 Dec 2022. Any suggested alternatives? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at NTE 374. It seems to match well.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I purchased the NTE374, and I found the marking guide for the transistor in the picture. The manufacturer's part number is KTA1704 but the part is marked as in the picture. Top line: K, middle line A1704, bottom line Y XXX where XXX is the manufacturing date.

Comment: @ScottBerger - If this answer is in fact the correct part then please mark it as the accepted answer.