# Interpreting the markings on transistors - convention to differentiate/identify part numbers vs manufacturing details vs. other data?

Tags: identification, components, datasheet, component-selection, markings

### General line of questioning:

When looking at transistor, are there any standards/conventions of how they are labeled?  Is it manufacturer specific - and if so, how would I identify that mfr's methodology?

### Specific situation:

I am looking to replace a friend transistor marked `K` `A1704` `Y*502` - the closest match I'm coming up with is a [KEC datasheet #KTA1704](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/69694/KEC/KTA1704.html).  Physical dimensions agree with the sheet, but I obviously can't confirm functionality/behavior.

The simple addition of a "T" into the string of characters found on the piece doesn't seem too far a jump - perhaps the 'T' is for transistor? - but I'm not particularly fond of guess-and-check to choose which component to stick into a circuit I don't have a map to.

Someone previously inquired about a nearly identical transistor in a [different question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/637369/transistor-part-number-and-equivalent-part), labeled `K` `A1704` `Y*852`.  OP had the same result of only locating the KTA 1704 - but what's to say that `Y 852` or `Y 502` aren't the part numbers and the similarity to KTA 1704 is coincidental?

---

### Bottom Line

**At what point do you conclude that the number on the part and the number on the sheet are "close enough" and that you've got the right sheet?**

---

Comment: Note: OP of the other question did eventually locate something that led him to conclude the association was accurate, and also
"found the marking guide for the transistor" indicating the bottom line is the manufacturing date.

Given that both our boards are from the same mfr, I'm willing to put trust in "some random comment on the internet" that I can't verify myself, and assume that the broken part I have in my hand is in fact a KTA1704.  

BUT, while this particular scenario is (assumed) to be resolved, I'd prefer to be more self-sufficient in this sort of situation in the future.

Answer (score 0):

There is no general standard for part markings, every manufacturer does it's own thing. Usually there are different marking elements:

- **Part code**: This is the number that identifies the device. In your case that's likely `A1704`. Depending on the size of the package and the internal conventions of the manufacturer, the part code can be a the full part number or just a short alpha numeric code. It's often, but not always, described in the datasheet. In your case it's not in the datasheet.
- **Manufacturer code**: This is often a logo, but it can also be just a code. In this case `K` probably stands for `KEC`.
- **Lot number**: A number that identifies a production batch. It's often used internally by the manufacturer to track parts in case there is a problem with a batch. It's usually completely undocumented and obviously changes between production batches. In this case that's probably what `502` means.
- **Date code**: A code that identifies the production time. Similar to a lot number, but more often described in the datasheet.
- **Location code**: A code that identifies at which facility the part was made if there are multiple.
- **Other**: There might be even more information. In this example the datasheet says "\$h_{fe}\$ Classification Y:100~200, GR:160~320". This is what `Y` could refer to as part of  the markings.

A part can have all of these elements or even non at all. If there is no datasheet to explain the markings, the only thing you can do is search for other pictures of the part. Usually the only important part of the marking is the part code. This number will be the same on all identical parts. Other numbers will probably change between batches. If the marking shares numbers with the part number, like here KT**A1704**, it's a good indicator that it's the part code. Sometimes the part code is visually separated from the other numbers. Date codes and lot numbers could be written on a different line or be rotated by 90°, for example.

It's hard to say at which point you can be certain that you have identified a part when there is no information about the markings in the datasheet. I would say if there are pictures online and the markings style (font, font size, number of characters) matches the part in question and there is just a small difference in some of the numbers (probably the lot/date code), then you can be pretty sure that you found the right part. The only way to be 100% sure would be to ask the manufacturer if they are still around.